# Как реализовать CRUD операции при работе со связанными списками ListView(сценарий Master/Details) по шаблону MVVM?

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

У меня есть View(окно) оно поделено разделителем на 2 части:в левой размещены Master и справа Details ListView. К Master и Details привязаны ObservableCollection. Сверху этого View имеется панель с кнопками с привязанными к ним Command(Add, Delete, Edit,...). Я сделал для каждого ListView свою модель представления и связал их с соответствующими ListView, назовем их MasterVM и DetailsVM. В каждой из них находится свойство CurrentElement типа IBaseElement. Оба ListView с флагом IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true. Имеются такие сущности:

```
public interface IBaseElement
{
    /// Уникальный номер элемента.
    int ID { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для классов описывающих элементы данных раздела Category.
public interface ICategoryElement : IBaseElement
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    /// Коллекция дополнительных параметров элемента.
    IList<IBaseElement> Details { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для любых классов описывающих элемент данных образца.
public interface ISampleElement : ICategoryElement
{
    /// Номер образца.
    int Number { get; set; }
    /// Диаметр образца.
    float Diametr { get; set; }
    /// Высота образца
    float Height { get; set; }
    /// Масса образца.
    float Mass { get; set; }
    /// Плотность образца.
    float Density { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для любых классов описывающих элемент данных стержня.
public interface IRodElement : ICategoryElement
{
    /// Номер стержня.
    int Number { get; set; }
    /// Материал стержня.
    string Material { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для любых классов описывающих элемент данных прибора.
public interface IDeviceElement : ICategoryElement
{
    /// Номер эталона.
    int Number { get; set; }
    /// Материал эталона.
    string Material { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для любых классов описывающих элемент данных эталона.
public interface IEtalonElement : ICategoryElement
{
    /// Номер эталона.
    int Number { get; set; }
    /// Материал эталона.
    string Material { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для любых классов описывающих детали отдельно взятого образца.
public interface ISampleDetails : IBaseElement
{
    /// Температура.
    float Temperature { get; set; }
    /// Теплоемкость.
    float HeatCapacity { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент N0_Nt.
    float N0_Nt { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для любых классов описывающих детали отдельно взятого стержня.
public interface IRodDetails : IBaseElement
{
    /// Температура.
    float Temperature { get; set; }
    /// Теплоемкость.
    float HeatCapacity { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для классов описывающих детали отдельно взятого устройства.
public interface IDeviceDetails : IBaseElement
{
    /// Температура.
    float Temperature { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент Kt.
    float Kt { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент Pk.
    float Pk { get; set; }
}
/// Интерфейс для любых классов описывающих детали отдельно взятого эталона.
public interface IEtalonDetails : IBaseElement
{
    /// Температура.
    float Temperature { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент N0_Nt.
    float N0_Nt { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент SigmaC.
    float SigmaC { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент Lambda_liter.
    float Lambda_liter { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент Lambda.
    float Lambda { get; set; }
    /// Коэффициент Sigma_Percent.
    float Sigma_Percent { get; set; }
}
```

Эти интерфейсы реализованы в соответствующих классах. Объекты типа ISampleElement, IRodElement, IDeviceElement, IEtalonElement это элементы коллекции Master, а с припиской Details это элементы Details. В левой части View есть ComboBox для выбора текущей группы с помощью такого перечисления:

```
/// Список категорий.
public enum Categories
{
    /// Образцы
    [Description("Образцы")]
    Samples,
    /// Стержень
    [Description("Стержень")]
    Rods,
    /// Прибор
    [Description("Прибор")]
    Devices,
    /// Эталон
    [Description("Эталон")]
    Etalons
}
```

Вид View задан в словаре ресурсов:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:wpf.test1.Framework.Converters"
                xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:wpf.test1.Enums"
                xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:wpf.test1.Framework.Helpers"
                xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">

<!--  ============== КОНВЕРТЕРЫ =================  -->
<!--  Конвертер колонок для GridView  -->
<converters:ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter x:Key="ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter" />

<!--  ============== СТИЛИ =================  -->
<!--  Стиль для элемента LV_CategoryItem из шаблона lv_CategoryDetailsTemplate  -->
<Style x:Key="LV_Item" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
<!--  Стиль для элемента GridViewColumnHeader списка lv_CategoryDetails  -->
<Style x:Key="LV_GridViewColumnHeader" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
<!--  Стиль LV_CategoryStyle  -->
<Style x:Key="LV_CategoryStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,5" />
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="View" Value="{Binding Category.ColumnsConfig, Converter={StaticResource ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter}}" />
</Style>
<!--  Стиль LV_ElementDetailsStyle  -->
<Style x:Key="LV_ElementDetailsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,5" />
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="View" Value="{Binding Details.ColumnsConfig, Converter={StaticResource ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter}}" />
</Style>


<!--  =====================  ШАБЛОНЫ =================  -->

<!--  Шаблон данных для отдельного элемента ItemsControl  -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditItemsTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Margin="2"
                 Text="{Binding Value,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<!--  Шаблон для пустого списка ItemsControl  -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EmptyListTemplate">
    <Border Margin="10"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Padding="10">
        <TextBlock>No items to display</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<!--  Стиль для ItemsControl панели редактирования свойств элемента  -->
<Style x:Key="EditItemsStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditItemsTemplate}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EmptyListTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EmptyListTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!--  Шаблон данных для View режима просмотра  -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ViewModeTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--  Панель кнопок  -->
        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0">
            <ComboBox Width="90"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={helpers:EnumerationExtension {x:Type enums:Categories}}}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Category.CurrentCategory}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value" />
            <Button Content="Add" />
            <Button Command="{Binding Delete}" Content="Delete" />
            <Button Command="{Binding DeleteAll}" Content="Delete All" />
            <Button Content="Update" />
            <Button Content="Edit" />
            <Button Command="{Binding FooCommand}" Content="Foo" />
        </ToolBar>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--  Мастер(Список элементов выбранной категории)  -->
            <ListView x:Name="LV_Master"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LV_Item}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Category.Items,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Category.CurrentElement,
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                             Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Style="{StaticResource LV_CategoryStyle}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetCurrentListCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:MasterDetail.Master}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ListView>
            <!--  Cписок с точками редактируемого элемента  -->
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Width="3"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <ListView x:Name="LV_Details"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="2"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LV_Item}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Details.Items,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                            Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Details.CurrentElement,
                                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                             Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Style="{StaticResource LV_ElementDetailsStyle}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetCurrentListCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:MasterDetail.Detail}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ListView>
            <!--  Разделитель  -->
        </Grid>
        <!--  Строка состояния  -->
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Статус:" />
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Это используется в окне так:

```
<Window
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource   ViewModeTemplate}" />
</Window>
```

Код конвертеров:

```
/// Класс конвертер для объекта GridView.
public class ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var config = value as ColumnsConfig;
        if (config != null)
        {
            var gridView = new GridView();
            foreach (var column in config.Columns)
            {
                var binding = new Binding(column.DataField);
                gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Header, DisplayMemberBinding = binding });
            }
            return gridView;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

//Код расширителя разметки:
public class EnumerationExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private Type _enumType;
    public EnumerationExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        if (enumType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumType");
        EnumType = enumType;
    }
    public Type EnumType
    {
        get { return _enumType; }
        private set
        {
            if (_enumType == value)
                return;
            var enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(value) ?? value;

            if (enumType.IsEnum == false)
                throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an Enum.");

            _enumType = value;
        }
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(EnumType);
        return (
          from object enumValue in enumValues
          select new EnumerationMember
          {
              Value = enumValue,
              Description = GetDescription(enumValue)
          }).ToArray();
    }
    private string GetDescription(object enumValue)
    {
        var descriptionAttribute = EnumType
          .GetField(enumValue.ToString())
          .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
          .FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;


        return descriptionAttribute != null
          ? descriptionAttribute.Description
          : enumValue.ToString();
    }
    public class EnumerationMember
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Идея такая: Пользователь выбирает в ComboBox нужную группу элементов(работает расширитель разметки для перечислений). View меняет колонки Master и Details ListView на соответствующие данным в коллекции Master(срабатывает конвертер). При выборе элемента в Master ListView должна сработать привязка для показа его подробностей в Details ListView. При этом данные для Details ListView должны браться из element.Details(поле Details это коллекция типа IList или что больше подойдет).

Вопросы: 1. Как настроить привязки для такой задачи?
2. Как реализовать добавление/удаление элементов в Master и Details ListView? Это те самые CRUD операции.

P.S. Не вижу кнопки для принятия ответа за "верный" могу только повышать очки ответов.

Comment: Хм. Странно. А почему при установке фокуса на другой элемент `CurrentElement` не обновляется? Должен, по идее. Что-то тут не так.

Comment: Может, покажите код? Без него непонятно. Может быть виновата какая-то глупая мелочь.